# Bash script invoking subshell due to pipping

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

lets say we have this script

```
#!bin/bash
count=0
count2=0
find "$1" -type f | while read file; do
count=$(($count +1))
find "$1" -type f | while read file2; do
count2=$(($count2 +1))
done
done
echo "count: $count" # prints 0
echo "count2: $count2" # prints 0
```

Now lets do a modification as follow:

```
#!bin/bash
count=0
count2=0
find "$1" -type f | {
while read file; do
count=$(($count +1))
find "$1" -type f | {
while read file2; do
count2=$(($count2 +1))
done
}
done
echo "count: $count" # prints some number
echo "count2: $count2" # prints 0
}
```

i know the problem lies in the subshell invoked by the pipe. The variables inside the subshell changes just inside the subshell and the changed values are not accessible from the main shell ( or at least something similar to this )

So my question is, is there any way to fix this? so that count2 prints its changed result ? ( other than writing and reading to a temp file, or changing the code to for loops ).
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Avoid the pipes; avoid the subshells:

```
#!bin/bash
count=0
count2=0
while read file; do
  count=$(($count +1))
  while read file2; do
    count2=$(($count2 +1))
  done < <(find "$1" -type f) 
done < <(find "$1" -type f) 
echo "count: $count"
echo "count2: $count2"
```

When you have a pipe, as you know, you have an implied subshell. Here, though, we just have a redirection from a file. `<(command)` is a process substitution – it creates a named pipe or /dev/fd filehandle with the output (or input if you use `>()`) of the given process. Then it expands to the name of the file.

```
$ echo <(echo)
/dev/fd/63
```

The space, therefore, is important. This is not the same as

```
while read; do …; done << (command)
```

That's just a syntax error!

What we're doing is closer to this:

```
find "$1" -type f > tmpfile
while read; do …; done < tmpfile
rm tmpfile
```

Except the file creation and cleanup are handled by the system.

Of course, if you just want to count files:

```
find "$1" -type f -exec bash 'echo $#' _ {} + # Works up to ARG_MAX

# If number of files > ARG_MAX:
sum() {
  local IFS=+
  bc <<< "$*"
}
sum $( find "$1" -type f -exec bash 'echo $#' _ {} + )
```

Comment: i am doing more than counting, so the the first way fits the most.

Answer (score 1):

You can use process substitution to avoid piping and hence creating subshell:

```
#!bin/bash
count=0
count2=0

while read -r file; do
   ((count++))
   while read -r file2; do
      ((count2++))
   done < <(find "$1" -type f)
done < <(find "$1" -type f)

echo "count: $count"
echo "count2: $count2"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `bash` 4, you can eliminate the calls to `find` along with the pipes.

```sh
#!bin/bash
count=0
count2=0
shopt -s globstar
for file in **/*; do
    [[ -f $file ]] || continue
    (( count++ ))
    for file2 in **/*; do
        [[ -f $file2 ]] || continue
        (( count2++ ))
    done
done

echo "count: $count" # prints some number
echo "count2: $count2" # prints 0
```

Comment: Yes i am using bash 4, but this doesn't work. a simple for loop: `for file in "$1"; do echo "$file"` doesn't seem to loop over subdirectories

Comment: You still need the `/*` to iterate over the *contents* of the directory: `for file in "$1"/*; do` iterates over the immediate contents of the directory whose name is in `$1`; `for file in "$1"/**/*; do` also recursively descends into any directories under `$1`.

Comment: Okay got it. Thanks its kinda faster than the one with `find` i guess